# strip punctuation from a file list

Tags: python, regex, list

```
3   3   how are you doing???
2   5   dear, where abouts!!!!!!........
4   6   don't worry i'll be there for ya///
```

I have a file with such type of sentences. I want to strip the punctuation from them. How can I loop and strip with regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> a="what is. your. name?"
>>> b=re.findall(r'\w+',a)
>>> b
['what', 'is', 'your', 'name']
```

I know to do only with 1 sentence but when it comes to a list like above then I get confused. I am new to python and regular expressions. It returns such type of error when I dont strip the punctutation in my sentences.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: multiple repeat
```

EDiteD:The sentences is the 3rd column & delimiter is tab so how do I remove punctuation from 3rd column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate lines using `for` loop:

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', line)
        # do something with words
```

---

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        col1, col2, rest = line.split('\t', 2) # split into 3 columns
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', rest)
        line = '\t'.join(col1, col2, ' '.join(words))
        # do something with words or line
```

Comment: Hi, in the file I got 2 more columns before the sentences then how do I remove punctuation only from last column

Comment: @jarvis, How do defined the column?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following script:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        print ' '.join(re.findall(r'\w+', line))
```

Demo:

```
$ chmod +x strip_punc.py

$ cat input
how are you doing???
dear, where abouts!!!!!!........
don't worry i'll be there for ya///

$ ./strip_punc.py input
how are you doing
dear where abouts
don t worry i ll be there for ya
```

Comment: Hi, in the file I got 2 more columns before the sentences then how do I remove punctuation only from last column

Comment: Post a representative example, you haven't given enough information.. what is the delimiter between columns, are they fixed width ect?

Answer (score 2):

Use this with a text file:

```
import re

reg = "\w+"
strings = []

with open("s.txt",'r') as txt:
    for i in txt.readlines():
        strings.append(' '.join(re.findall(reg,i)))

print strings
```

Output:

```
['how are you doing', 'dear where abouts', 'don t worry i ll be there for ya']
```

Comment: @jarvis It simply joins a space in this case to the output of the `re.findall(reg,i)` so if the output was `['how', 'are', 'you', 'doing']`the `join()` method iterates over it and adds a space so the final output is `how are you doing`